# "With high probability" statement from CLT

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ i.i.d. with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, so that
\begin{equation}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\longrightarrow N(0,1)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)
\end{equation}
in distribution.

Then I know that $(*)$ implies
\begin{equation}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}=O_p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right).    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(**)
\end{equation}

But I wasn't sure if (*) also implies the following statement: "With high probability, 
\begin{equation}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\left|\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma^2}\right|\leq c\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(***)
\end{equation}
for some constant $c>0$. Lastly, I can see that $(***)$ implies $(**)$ but is it true the other way around?

Comment: I think sigma should not be squared when dividing the deviation from mu. Normalization is division by the standard deviation.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for your point. Corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The following holds: For every $c$ and $n$, consider the event $$A_{n,c}=\left[\left|\bar{X}-\mu\right|\leqslant\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}} \right].$$ Then, for every positive $\varepsilon$, there exists some finite $c$ such that, for every $n$, $$P(A_{n,c})\geqslant1-\varepsilon.$$ Is this what you need as a reformulated $(\ast\ast\ast)$?